# Usage of the preposition 'in' two times in a row?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

The sentence: "This means that if you are in any way different, you could possibly find yourself in a column in a newspaper"

I am not sure whether it is correct to have 'in' two times in a row, maybe on a newspaper? But that sounds incorrect too..

Comment: It's fine to repeat a preposition. *"In a canyon, in a cavern, ..."*

Comment: What you have written is fine, but "in a newspaper column" is briefer and avoids the duplication if it bothers you. Frankly, "could possibly" strikes me as more redundant.

Comment: @jejorda2 Thank you, that does indeed sound more eloquent. Do you have a suggestion for "Could possibly?" Or should I just remove the word "Possibly"?

Comment: try removing the second phrase by saying "in a newspaper column".

Comment: @jejorda2 excuse me, why using "could possibly" is redundant in your opinion? I don't think it is as I have seen alot of people speaking that way, so it's normal and always used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule against using the same preposition in consecutive prepositional phrases:

> I was in my suit in a car in a hold in a boat in the middle of the Atlantic
>   Ocean.

I'm hard pressed to think of an example right off, but I'd venture to say that there have been many writers who have employed doing so as a literary scheme or a rhetorical device, that even the best writers have done exactly this.

***Update:***

I knew I'd come up with a literary example:

> I would not, could not, ***in*** the rain,
>
> not ***in*** the dark, not on a train,
>
> not ***in*** a car, not ***in*** a tree.
>
> I do not like them, Sam, you see,
>
> not ***in*** a house, not ***in*** a box,
>
> not ***with*** a mouse, not ***with*** a fox.
>
> I will not eat them here or there.
>
> I do not like them anywhere!

-*Green Eggs and Ham* by Dr. Seuss.

Comment: Welcome to 3K reputation club. Now you can close-vote and reopen-vote. Please see [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).